# Edit order details in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The standard way to edit a record in ASP.NET MVC is the following:

```
//
// GET: /Movies/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(movie);
}

//
// POST: /Movies/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

The problem is that I need to edit order details (1 order, many details) and therefore based on two IDs (the order and the product ones). It does not work (I cannot get an OrderDetail item as action parameter). How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

```
//
// GET: /Orders/EditDetails
public ActionResult EditDetails(int id, string productID)
{
   OrderDetail od = GetOrderDetail(id, productID);

   return View(od);
}

//
// POST: /Orders/EditDetails
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditDetails(OrderDetail od)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      context.Entry(od).State = EntityState.Modified;
      context.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   return View(od);
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is the code requested by Shimmy:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditDetails", "Orders", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.quantity)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.quantity)

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.productID)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.productID, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewBag.productList, "productID", "fullProductName"))

   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.orderID)
}
```

Comment: You will have to share your Razor code. It will tell us how you the form data is posted back to server.

Comment: @Shimmy: I added the Razor code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the `OrderDetail.Id` itself as well as the `OrderDetail.OrderId` and the `OrderDetail.MovieId` properties are all present in the form as a hidden field.

In that way, when you post it back to the server you have track on what `Movie` and `Order` this `OrderDetail` is of, in the action.

Comment: In this live example I don't see any *nested but separate view*

Comment: I have this in my question edit: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.orderID)`

Comment: You should also include the `MovieId` and the `OrderId` in your form. In the action, you can then re-retrieve it back and keep track of it.

Comment: How can I retrieve an hidden value in my action?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `collection["DateFrom"]`? Isn't there anything better?

Comment: Aren't those properties part of your entity? Once you include them in the form, razor will post the form back as the entity with those properties set the their matching form values.